# Connecting pyspark cluster to Cassandra cluster ERROR o64.load

Tags: pyspark, cassandra, datastax-enterprise, spark-cassandra-connector

I am trying to connect my PySpark cluster to Cassandra cluster. I did the following to set the connector from Spark to Cassandra:

```
./bin/spark-submit --packages com.datastax.spark:spark-cassandra-connector_2.10:1.5.0-M2 ./exaples/testing.py
```

I set the following in my python file:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

SPARK_IP = "ip-111-11-1-1.us-west-2.compute.internal"
SPARK_PORT = "7077"
CASSANDRA_PORT = "222.22.2.22"

conf = SparkConf() \
   .setMaster("spark://%s:%s" % (SPARK_IP, SPARK_PORT)) \
   .set("spark.cassandra.connection.host", CASSANDRA_PORT)
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
```

In my Cassandra cluster I created a keyspace and a table. I then try to read from Cassandra in pyspark and do the following:

```
sqlContext.read \
.format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra") \
.options(table="poop", keyspace="demo") \
.load().show()
```

I get the following error and I'm not sure how to fix this:

> Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/usr/local/spark/examples/testing.py", line 37, in 
>       .options(table="poop", keyspace="demo") \
>     File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/readwriter.py", line 155, in load
>     File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1133, in **call**
>     File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/utils.py", line 63, in deco
>     File "/usr/local/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
>   py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o64.load.
>   : java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Failed to find data source: org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra. Please find packages at http://spark.apache.org/third-party-projects.html